# Using Transaction scope to wrap Rhino ETL Processes

Tags: scope

I'm using Rhino ETL for handling both SQL SERVER and Excel file Extraction/Load.

I've put more than one ETL processes (which insert data into sql server tables) in a transaction scope (c#) so that I can rollback the whole process in case of any errors or exceptions.

I'm not sure if C# transaction scope could be used along with ETL processes, but the way I did is as follows:

```
private void ELTProcessesInTransaction(string a, string b, int check)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {

       using (ETLProcess1 etlProcess1 = new ETLProcess1(a, b))
       {
           etlProcess1.Execute();
       }
       using (ETLProcess2 etlProcess2 = new ETLProcess2(a, b))
       {
           etlProcess2.Execute();
       }
       if (!_InSeverDB.HasError(check))
          scope.Complete();//Commits based on a condition
    }
}
```

This does not rollback the transaction at all. I tried removing the scope.Complete() line, still the process is getting committed.

Please let me know where I need to correct or if the whole approach is incorrect.